# How in ASP.NET MVC to change Url.Encode character replacement strategy?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, encoding, configuration

I'm using Url.Encode within a view and it's replacing spaces with + so instead of:

**/production/cats-the-musical** I'm getting **.../cats+the+musical**.

I'm sure this is an easy one, but where do you go to configuring which characters are used for this?

I'll be doing this:

```
public static string EncodeForSEO(this UrlHelper helper, string unencodedUrl)
{
     return helper.Encode(unencodedUrl.Replace(' ', '-'));
}
```

Until I get a better answer from you guys.

**Edit:** Thanks Guffa for pointing out my hasty coding.

Comment: don't forget to take care of special chars

Comment: These would be taken care of by the call to Encode anyway, wouldn't they?

Comment: Just a comment in general: Url Path encoding is different from Url Parameter encoding. The "+" characters in the path is not a correct replacement for the space " " character and would cause issues. For SEO as you've done above, replacing " " with "-" is a good technique though. MVC can make it appear that paths and query string parameters are interchangeable, but they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change which characters the UrlEncode method uses, the use of "+" for spaces is defined in the standards for how an URL is encoded, using "-" instead would mean that the method would change the value and not just encoding it. As the "-" character is not encoded, there would be no way to decode the string back to the original value.

In your method, there is no need to check for the character before doing the replacement. If the Replace method doesn't find anything to replace, it just returns the original string reference.

```
public static string EncodeForSEO(this UrlHelper helper, string unencodedUrl) {
   return helper.Encode(unencodedUrl.Replace(' ', '-'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code fix.

It's more than just encoding, specifically it's making the url parameters more SEO friendly.

On the controller side though a call to HttpUtility.Decode will decode any parts of the parameters that were encoded normally.

Comment: Hm... Why would "cast-the-musical" be more SEO friendly than "cats the musical"?

Comment: Who knows, I was told it was the google-preferred way by an SEO specialist at a talk I attended. Stack Overflow seems to do the same thing too.

Comment: The -'s are a lot nicer on the eyeballs, too.

Comment: -1 spaces are fine. modern web browsers don't even show them as anything other than spaces. @Robert Paulson is correct with UrlPathEncode.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: What do you mean by "spaces are fine"? Are you saying that spaces should be used in URLs, while the standard explicitly forbids it? Just because it works in some browsers doesn't make it correct.

Comment: @Guffa spaces encoded properly as they are in UrlPathEncode. Modern web browsers don't show urls with %20 any more, they display `/cats the musical`

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: I don't see where you get this from. The answer doesn't contain anything about `%20` being displayed in one way or the other. So, what is it that you think is wrong with the answer?

Comment: `unencodedUrl.Replace(' ', '-')` is wrong to do. `UrlPathEncode(unencodedUrl)` is correct to do.

Answer (score 4):

*I want to draw attention to Path versus Query String encoding differences*

MVC allows / encourages us to write paths (routes) that can be easier to remember than query strings. e.g. `/Products.aspx?id=1` could, in MVC, be `/Products/View/1`

Building on that, it also encourages, for SEO friendliness, other data that may or may not be necessary like `/Products/View/1/Coffee`

If the name has space characters, or a necessary parameter is a string containing space characters, and you are including it in the Url *path*, one of 2 things must happen because a ' ' cannot be left in a Url Path or Query string parameter without being encoded.

1. You must `UrlPathEncode()` the string
2. first you transform the spaces in the string,

   - then call `UrlPathEncode()` as you may have other characters requiring encoding.

*Note*: there is a big difference between Url Encoding (meant for query strings) and Url Path Encoding (meant for path portions of Urls)

- `cats the musical` -> UrlEncode -> `cats+the+musical` 
  -- this is *not* valid in a url *path*
- `cats the musical` -> UrlPathEncode -> `cats%20the%20musical`

If you're following along; going back to Web Forms vs MVC - `/Products.aspx?name=Coffee+Beans` would be rewritten as `/Products/View/Coffee%20Beans`

So that leaves us where OP's question starts. Q: How do you get *SEO and human Friendly* Urls? Q: Use @Guffas code to replace the " " with "-" in your own code before UrlPathEncoding the rest.

In sites I've worked on, when we have a user-entered value used only for SEO (like a blog title or similar) we go a step further normalizing the string output by collapsing successive spaces into a single "-" e.g.

```
cats         the     musical
```

which would otherwise be `cats-----the-----musical` becomes `cats-the-musical`

Comment: You no longer need to replace spaces with hyphens. Modern browsers will create pretty urls for you, no more %20soup.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic thanks for the update. It appears Chrome and Firefox will now interpret that a user meant to encode the url, and are not as strict with their users; they will encode ' ' to %20 for them. Firefox will display spaces, but Chrome will still displays the %20's in the address bar. However the underlying issue is that the spec isn't going away, and a %20 in the url, which is still required, is not "human friendly". People cut and paste urls outside of these browsers, and both Firefox and Chrome will still encode the urls correctly.